# C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'ReportingServices2005.ServerInfoHeader' to ReportingServices2005.Warning[]'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

follow this to add my webservice:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154052%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx
http://server/reportserver/ReportService2005.asmx?wsdl

then following this to try to deploy a report
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2005.reportingservice2005.createreport.aspx

I get the error located here

```
warnings = rs.CreateReport(name, "/Samples", false, definition, null);
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'ReportingServices2005.ServerInfoHeader' to ReportingServices2005.Warning[]'

For the life of me I can't figure out why i'm getting this following this exact layout, am I suppose to be using, ReportExecution2005.asmx?wsdl?

Am I using the wrong web services?

Comment: I was adding a webservice as a regular service, in VS2010 make sure you go into advanced.

Answer (score 0):

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/273853-c-web-service-returning-objects

Comment: Please summarize the linked page.